# Python Json Process

Tags: python-3.x

this is my code

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/Art.json').json()

print(r['data'])
```

this code sometimes work but sometimes get fail

Exception is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/SAMET/Desktop/python/a.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(r['data'])
KeyError: 'data'
```

Comment: It simply means that response data doesn't have the key value `data`. You can add a check ` if 'data' in r. keys() :`

Answer (score -1):

You must use `r.data`. `r['data']` could work in Javascript, but in Python you can't access objects as dictionaries.

Comment: Seems like `r` actually is a dictionary.